# javascript for iteration of css class for the read more link to work

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I make a description of products, in which half of the texts show up on clicking the read more link. There are numbers of products with description in a row. The products are coming from a loop in ruby on rails. So i provide the remaining text class for each product description like class1, class2, class3 etc.

Then for one product description, i write javascript as:

```
 $(function(){
   $('.read_more1').click(function(event){ 

     event.preventDefault();
     $('.more_text1').show();
     $('.read_more1').hide();

   });
 });
```

But as there are random number of products . So how can i iterate the class for working of the read more link for all numbers of products are present.

Ruby .html.erb code

```
<% if @example[:products] %>
  <% @example.company.each do |company| %>
    <% if !company[:display_company] %>
    <div class="field no_margin">
      <b class="space-bold"><%= company[:category_name].titleize %>
      </b>

    <% file_name = 
       get_file_name_from_url(company.public.first.photo_url) %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(file_public_path(url: @example[:url], \
                            id: company._id.to_s, mod_id: company.public.first._id.to_s, \ ), \
                            company_public_path(url: @example[:url], id: company._id.to_s) %>
    <div class="linespace">
      <%= ("company[:category])[0..30]} #{ link_to t('more'),  \
          { :pics=> true}, { :class => "read_more#{count}"}} <text class=more_text#{count}>#{t(company[:category])[31..-1]}
           </text>").html_safe %><br />

      <% count += 1 %>  

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Its complex to understand.

Comment: If anyone want more info., can ask

Comment: Can you provide your sample html of 2 or 3 products

Comment: Try to provide a snippet (jsfiddle) maybe? And simulate the description of products, would be very helpful to understand what you wanna achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector that selects for any class that starts by a given string
Something like:

```
$(function(){
     $('[class^="read_more"]').click(function(event){ 

       event.preventDefault();
       let suffix = this.className.split('read_more')[1];
       $(`[class^="more_text${suffix}"]`).show();
       $(`[class^="read_more${suffix}"]`).hide();

   });
});
```

Comment: I would definitely not use the name with the id in the class name, I would use `id` for this purpose, and then `more_text` without id, and then find it as child node.

Comment: Thanks, it takes my whole day